# Response Not getting save in model in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have to send the requests to "http:example.com/api/galleries/gallery_id/photos.The gallery_id is varying and I am getting it from params.id. Now the  problem I am facing is that the response from a server is an array  of objects.So what should I use?By That, I meant (findAll or findRecord).When I use FindRecord it make the correct call But is not able to serialize the data.When I use findAll it calls the wrong API.

My Serializer

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
  isNewSerializerAPI: true,
  primaryKey:'pk',
  normalize: function(typeClass, hash) {
    console.log(hash)
    var fields = Ember.get(typeClass, 'fields');
    fields.forEach(function(field) {
      var payloadField = Ember.String.underscore(field);
      if (field === payloadField) { return; }
      hash[field] = hash[payloadField];
      delete hash[payloadField];
    });
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

This is the error I am getting is

```
Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for gallery in an object passed to 'push'
```

Comment: Do you provide a valid value for 'pk' because you defined it as primaryKey, if you want to work with id instead set 'id' as primaryKey?

Comment: @ChristianStengel I have specified "pk" as my primaryKey in other serializer also and it works fine.The problem I think is findRecord should return only on object.But In my case it is returing a array and that why it is not able to serialize.

Comment: Which adapter are you using? I notice you are extending JSONSerializer which is the most basic one.